# jQuery cycle2 and 'continueAuto'

Tags: jquery-cycle2

I have a simple [cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/) slideshow with a pager. The slideshow proceeds automatically (ie. with set `speed` and `timeout`). What I want to achieve is, that once the user clicks a link in the pager, the slideshow becomes "manual" (the automatic transitioning stops) and from that point it is controllable solely by the pager.
The [cycle2 API documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/) says that there is the 'continueAuto' option which should serve the purpose. So I made a handler to the `cycle-pager-activated` event like this:

```
$('#fp_slideshow').on('cycle-pager-activated', function(event, opts ) {
    $('#fp_slideshow').cycle({continueAuto: false});
});
```

The event gets called as I expect (upon clicking a link in the pager), but calling `cycle({continueAuto: false})` does nothing and the slideshow goes on indefinetely.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd like to see an answer to this as well. I've also tried the stop command to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The [pause command](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/#commands) might work better for you in this instance. I tried using the `cycle-pager-activated` event but couldn't get it to work consistently so instead attached a click handler directly to the pager links. Here's the JavaScript:

```
var $fp_slideshow = $('#fp_slideshow');

$fp_slideshow.cycle({
    pager: '#fp_slideshow_pager',
    pagerTemplate: '<li><a href="">Slide {{slideNum}}</a></li>'
});

$('a', '#fp_slideshow_pager').on('click', function() {
    $fp_slideshow.cycle('pause');
});
```

And here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N43KH/1/